# Django, template cannot be found

Tags: django, django-templates

For some reason the webapp I created, cannot find the template. I tried also to place the html file into several different location, but it still won't find it. As of now I have placed my template director at the following location `C:\xampp\htdocs\django_proj\templates\`. Do someone else know what the problem could be.

I have another webapp in this django project. The model and view, look almost the same, however that webapp can find the templates.

**/webapp/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField() 
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**/webapp/views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list

from models import Profile

def profile_list(request):
    return object_list(request,
        queryset=Profile.objects.all(),
        template_name='/webapp/list.html',
        template_object_name='profiles')
```

**/webapp/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^list/$', views.profile_list, name='profile_list'),
)
```

**/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import *

    urlpatterns = patterns('',

         (r'^webapp/', include('webapp.urls')),
    )
```

**/templates/webapp/list.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
  Test
  </body>
</html>
```

Error message

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /webapp/list/

/webapp/list.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/webapp/list/
Django Version:     1.4 pre-alpha
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

/webapp/list.html

Exception Location:     c:\tools\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in find_template, line 138
Python Executable:  c:\tools\python27\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.2
Python Path:    

['C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\webnotes',
 'c:\\tools\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'c:\\tools\\python27\\DLLs',
 'c:\\tools\\python27\\lib',
 'c:\\tools\\python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'c:\\tools\\python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'c:\\tools\\python27',
 'c:\\tools\\python27\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 12 Jan 2012 19:33:48 +0100
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

    Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
    Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
```

Comment: Do you get an error page with the "template not found error"?  Can you post the error message?  It usually contains a list of paths Django looks in for templates.  Also, any relevant Django settings would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your template name contains the *aboslute* path `/webapp/list.html`.  Try making it a relative path `webapp/list.html` so that `os.path.join(.)` handles path concatenation as intended.

Try this:

```
def profile_list(request):
    return object_list(request,
        queryset=Profile.objects.all(),
        template_name='webapp/list.html', # removed slash here.
        template_object_name='profiles')
```

Comment: Ahh, such a small thing. Thanks saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your url pattern on **/webapp/urls.py** from:

```
url(r'^list/$', views.profile_list, name='profile_list'),
```

to

```
url(r'^webapp/list/$', views.profile_list, name='profile_list'),
```

Comment: However I already added that part in `/urls.py`, so adding it into `/webapp/urls.py` will cause it not to find the url.